# Forcing a fixed-width table's cell to have the precise defined width

Tags: html, css, html-table

Basically I have a `<table>` taking up the whole available width of the screen. Sometimes I might have many cells, thus providing a base width to each `<col>` is helpful, to make sure it won't truncate badly.

I also, no matter the case, have a checkbox as the first column. I always want this to have a 31px width (**precisely 31px**). I'm okay if the rest of the cells don't take their precise width, but something like a percentage of the available space, based on the specified width, something it seems to do internally right now.

Problem is, if the `<table>` takes the whole width of the screen (**and i need it to take the whole width of the screen**), and I happen to have a few coulmns (let's say 4 columns) all with a defined width, the checkbox column will be lengthier:

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7wwp53aw/2/

I also included in the fiddle the desired table look.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7wwp53aw/3/ remove `width:100%` of `table`

Comment: I need it to take the whole width of the screen.

Comment: Your fiddle contains an “ideally it should look like this” part, which shows a formatted HTML table (not just an image). So why don’t you use that code??

Comment: Because there's an option to display more columns, and because of that, i'd like to provide a default width to each cell (based on it's type - a cell with long text will get a larger width, while a cell containing a small integer will get a small one). I currently can't guess when it's normal to disable the width of other columns just to make sure my checkbox column has the precise width. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: I also see someone voted to close the question, not sure why. Maybe explain yourself, mysterious voter ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to allow at least one of the columns to be free of width.
If they all have a width defined then it is used as a ratio of the whole table to use..

```
<colgroup>
    <col style="width: 31px;">
    <col>
    <col style="width: 100px;">
    <col style="width: 100px;">
</colgroup>
```

Or you can leave all but one, so that they get auto-width based on contents..

```
<colgroup>
    <col style="width: 31px;">
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
</colgroup>
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/7wwp53aw/8/

Answer (score 1):

Since you gave the table a width (100%) there is no reason to give every cell a width. Leave the width for the cells where you don't care and it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/7wwp53aw/7/

```
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 31px;">
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
    </colgroup>
```